# Como impedir que uma área do HTML seja clicável?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Existe alguma forma de impedir que uma área seja 'clicável' usando JavaScript ou CSS?

Comment: Creio que `pointer-events: none;` na área desejada já seja o suficiente.

Comment: Já tentei e não resolveu...

Comment: Edite a pergunta acrescentando um código de exemplo e explique melhor o que deseja. Aí a pergunta poderá ser reaberta, se for o caso.

Comment: A pergunta ficou muito genérica e as respostas marcadas como duplicada atendem nesse contexto.